# AESManaged Encryption/Decryption - Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: c#-4.0, cryptography, aes

I am coding an encryption/decryption aes utility with specific requirements:
-AES/CBC/PKCS7
-256-Bit Key provided as base64 string
-IV provided as base64 string

So I am trying to encryp/decrypt this string "1234567890123456" using the same key and IV. Encryption runs fine but when trying to decrypt the encrypted string I get the "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" exception. What am I missing?

//This is the calling test method

```
     public void Test_AESEncryption_Decrypt()
     {
         try
         {
             var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
             var key = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("JVSwvtTHhGHKmH7HIj5clsfQRXGg9ZZ0cOojoAPcGg0="));
             var iv = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("IgEfBiIIHBANIRccFhwJDg==")); 
             var strtoencrypt = "1234567890123456";
             var encrypted = AESEncryption.Encrypt(encoding,strtoencrypt, key, iv, CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode.PKCS7,128);


             var decrypted = AESEncryption.Decrypt(encoding,encoding.GetString(encrypted), key, iv, CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode.PKCS7,128);

             Assert.AreEqual(strtoencrypt, decrypted);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
         }

     }
```

//This is my Utility Class:

public static class AESEncryption
    {

```
    public static byte[] Encrypt(Encoding encoding, string strtoencrypt, string key, string iv, CipherMode mode, PaddingMode padding, int blocksize){

        var mstream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            var keybytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);

            aes.BlockSize = blocksize;
            aes.KeySize = keybytes.Length * 8;
            aes.Key = keybytes;
            aes.IV = encoding.GetBytes(iv);
            aes.Mode = mode;
            aes.Padding = padding;


            using (var cstream = new CryptoStream(mstream, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                var bytesToEncrypt = encoding.GetBytes(strtoencrypt);
                cstream.Write(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length);
                cstream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }

        }

        var encrypted = mstream.ToArray();
        return encrypted;
    }



    public static string Decrypt(Encoding encoding,string strencrypted, string key, string iv, CipherMode mode, PaddingMode padding, int blocksize)
    {

        var decrypted = "";

        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            var keybytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);

            aes.BlockSize = blocksize;
            aes.KeySize = keybytes.Length * 8;
            aes.Key = keybytes;
            aes.IV = encoding.GetBytes(iv);
            aes.Mode = mode;
            aes.Padding = padding;

            using (var mstream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(strencrypted)))
            {
                using (var cstream = new CryptoStream(mstream, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var sreader = new StreamReader(cstream))
                    {
                        decrypted = sreader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return decrypted;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your key is 56 bytes long when it gets to the encrypt method that due to the encoding, but you can't have this if your using AesManaged, AesManaged will only accept 16 byte (128 bit) key and same for the IV.

If you want to use 256 bit key encryption then you need to switch to RijndaelManaged. Aes specification does not support variable key lengths. It only uses fixed key lengths (128, 192 or 256 bits).

If you need variable key lengths then you may need to look at RC2 that supports key lengths for anything between 8–128 bits.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to use 256 bit key
>   encryption then you need to switch to
>   RijndaelManaged. Aes specification
>   does not support variable key lengths.
>   It only uses fixed key lengths (128,
>   192 or 256 bits).

As far as i know AES supports only a fixed blocksize of 128 bit but u can still use a 256 bit key. So if youre fine with a blocksize of 128 bit you can still stick with the aesmanaged class.

correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You assume that

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(x))==x
```

but that is not true for an arbitrary bytearray.

If you really need to encode the bytearray as a string, you should use Base-64.