# Encoding, decoding and re-encoding not producing original results

Tags: c#

I suspect that my decoding is not working properly. That is why I am testing it by encoding, decoding and the re-encoding to see if I am getting the same result. That is however not the case.

I encoded a `byte[]` named `model.PDF` to a `base64` string.

Now, for decoding, I converted `model.PDF` to a decoded `base64` string. However the output looks faulty or corrupted upon debugging and I suspect this is where something is going wrong.

To encode again, the decoded data is turned into `byte[]` again and then into an encoded `base64` string. However `base64EncodedData` does not match `plainTextEncodedData`. Please help me create a flawless encode to decode to re-encode flow.

```
// ENCODING - Byte array -> base64 encoded string
string base64EncodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(model.PDF);

// DECODING - Byte array -> base64 decoded string
var base64DecodedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(model.PDF);

// ENCODING AGAIN
byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64DecodedData);
var plainTextEncodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

To elaborate, the re-encoding matches the initial encoding perfectly if executed like this.

```
var PDF = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("redgreenblue");

string base64EncodedData  = Convert.ToBase64String(PDF);

// DECODING - Byte array -> base64 decoded string
var base64DecodedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PDF);

// ...
```

But, my `model.PDF` is fetched from the database as shown below, in which case the re-encoding does not match.

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    model.PDF = reader["PDF"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (byte[])reader["PDF"];
}
```

On an online base64 decoder (https://www.base64decode.org/), decoding an example value of `base64EncodedData` shows the ideal and correct value.

```
%PDF-1.5
%
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-IN) /StructTreeRoot 8 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 4 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Author(admin) /CreationDate(D:20190724114817+05'30') 
/ModDate(D:20190724114817+05'30') /Producer(Microsoft Excel 2013) /Creator(Microsoft Excel 2013) >>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 6 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 5 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 171>>
stream

...
```

However, in my program, the value of `base64DecodedData` shows up in its entirety as:

```
%PDF-1.5
%����
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-IN) /StructTreeRoot 8 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 4 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Author(admin) /CreationDate(D:20190724114817+05'30') 
/ModDate(D:20190724114817+05'30') /Producer(��
```

The 2 look similar in ways but my program seems to be producing a corrupt version of what the actual base64 decoded string should be.

Comment: Encoding.UTF8 will not create base64 strings. It interpreters bytes as binary saved utf8 data. You should check each variable in the debugger.

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData)` This just reverses the previous step. What's the point of doing that? And the variable name `base64EncodedBytes` --> Umm nope, nothing is encoded here; you're just back where you started.

Comment: `FromBase64String` decodes, `ToBase64String` encodes. That's it. Why are you doing all this `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` stuff?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I changed the code and simplified it based on your comment.

Comment: @PezanneKhambatta I think your code now works, doesn't it? `base64EncodedData ` and `plainTextEncodedData` should be the same.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Base64. The root cause of the problem is that `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(someByteArray));` is _**not**_ guaranteed to return a byte array that is equivalent to the original `someByteArray`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9740553/4934172) for more. Just use `Convert.ToBase64String` and `Convert.FromBase64String`. Are these two not enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't \`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x))==x\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740553/why-isnt-encoding-utf8-getbytesencoding-utf8-getstringx-x)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed From cursory reading, that does not explain `faulty or corrupted` output as the OP stated. That shouldn't happen from encoding-decoding. It comes down to: `model.PDF` probably isn't  correct UTF8.

Comment: @KekuSemau PDF [can have different encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656899/4934172). Moreover, even if it was valid UTF8 (which is unlikely), the `UTF8.GetBytes` method is [still not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9740590/4934172)  to produce the same _original bytes_ as I stated above.

Comment: Since when you use `Encoding.Something.GetString()` to get the bytes of a binary file? Unless you really want to destroy it. The byte of a binary file do not represent a string in any way. What code points should these values be converted to?

Comment: I would now mark this as a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1445520/what-does-%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%9F-in-the-2nd-line-of-pdf-files-mean, but I can't because it's not on SO.

Comment: Maybe you are using wrong way to  read `model.pdf` file that corrupts the encoding. Which method you are using to Read `model.pdf` file?

Answer (score 1):

A PDF is an ASCII file that can contain binary data (including strings in other encodings).
So you cannot read it as plain text.

> If a PDF file contains binary data, as most do [...] the header line
>   shall be immediately followed by a comment line containing at least
>   four binary characters—that is, characters whose codes are 128 or
>   greater.

Taken from [this answer, which has some more infos](https://superuser.com/questions/1445520/what-does-%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%9F-in-the-2nd-line-of-pdf-files-mean)

You see exactly these four characters in your own output.

Comment: Fair enough. Could you please explain what you think the online converter is doing different from my program?

Comment: It seems that the online tool ignores some non-printable bytes.